# Confusion in using Tensorflow 2.0 addson seq2seq BasicDecoder

Tags: tensorflow, seq2seq

Below is the code snippet of calling decoder() without sequence_length argument. Other codes are omitted for clarity.

```
decoder_cell = keras.layers.LSTMCell(units)
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(len(OUTPUT_CHARS) + 1)

decoder = tfa.seq2seq.basic_decoder.BasicDecoder(decoder_cell,
                                                 sampler,
                                                 output_layer=output_layer)
final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = decoder(
    decoder_embeddings,
    initial_state=encoder_state) # NOTE: without sequence_lengths argument here!
```

Second example of calling decoder is shown below from the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326767/adapting-tensorflow-rnn-seq2seq-model-code-for-tensorflow-2-0)

```
final_outputs, final_state, final_sequence_lengths = decoder(
decoder_embeddings, initial_state=encoder_state,
sequence_length=sequence_lengths) # NOTE: it use sequence_lengths of input tensor
```

Would you please help to clarify below confusions?

1. when shall we pass `sequence_lengths` argument to `decoder()` and when is it unnecessary?
2. The `BasicDecoder` inherits the `BaseDecoder` which does not have the `sequence_lengths` argument in its `call` method. The source code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/5f618fdb92d9737da059de2a33fa606e97505398/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq/decoder.py#L159) Why does it work when pass in `sequence_lengths` argument to `decoder()`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I found somewhere in the doc with sequence_length argument here https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/BaseDecoder?hl=en#initialize